# Telescoping series and finding formulas for sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

This problem is from Spivak's calculus book .

So here he shows us how to derive this formula : $\;\; 1^2+...+\;n^2 $

And he begins with : $ \;\;\;\;(k+1)^3 - k^3 = 3k^2 + 3k +1  $ ,  where $\;\; k = 1,...,n$

So writing it down and counting we start with : $$ 2^3 -\;1^3=3.1^2+3.1+1$$ $$3^3-\;2^3=3.2^2+3.2+1$$ $$.$$ $$.$$$$.$$ $$(n+1)^3-n^3=\;3.n^2+3.n+1\\$$
Now here is where I am confused , he presents **this** :$$$$ $$(n+1)^3-1=3.[1^2+...+n^2]+3.[1+...n]+n\\$$
Where did the "1" come from on the left hand side of the equation ? And where did the "n" come from at the far right hand side of the equation ?

Comment: The $n$ comes from summing $1,$ $n$ times

Comment: We have $1=1^3$ as the motivation for the $1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to MSE 7210!

What is done there is just adding all of the $n$ equations together. This way on the left-hand side you get:
$$[(n+1)^3-n^3]+[n^3-(n-1)^3]+\ldots+[2^3-1^3],$$
which is where the $(n+1)^3-1$ came from. The $n$ on the right-hand side is an effect of adding $n$ copies of $1$, since all of the terms are of form $3\cdot k^2+3\cdot k +1$, so end with a "$1$".

Answer (score 1):

The terms $2^3,3^3,\cdots n^3$ get cancelled if we add the equations.
So in the LHS we have $$(n+1)^3-1^3 = (n+1)^3-1$$

---

We have n-equations.  So, $$1+1+1+\cdots+1\text{ (n -times)} = n$$